# On windows Server 2019 nvidia-smi cannot show the correct installed version of CUDA

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvcc, nvidia-smi

when I try nvidia-smi I am getting this:
CUDA version:12.2

But i have uninstalled 12.2 version and installed 11.2,

while trying in nvcc --version cmd am getting this 11.2 version only,

**nvcc:
NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2020
NVIDIA Corporation Built on Mon_Nov_30_19:15:10_PDT_2020 Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2,
V11.2.67 Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0
**

Tensorflow version==2.9.0
python version= 3.10

I have uninstalled all related to 12.2 cuda version from the machine

Comment: `nvidia-smi` is part of the NVIDIA driver package. The CUDA version reported by `nvidia-smi` is the *maximum* CUDA version supported by the installed driver package. `nvidia-smi` provides no information regarding any installed versions of CUDA.